# Database for chat

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a chat for a site and I'm wondering if the db solution is the best one in case of a large amount of users.

In case the db is an acceptable solution I would like to know which is the best way to design it:

1. Is one table enough to store all the messages from all the users? Do I have to store each message everytime a user send it (like a simple "hello" in one record)?
2. Do I have to create a separate tables for each chat?

Obviously assuming that the indexing and the partitioning are made.

I'm scared about the performance at this stage (db level). Then I can concentrate better to the middleware section and manage it there.

Comment: Make it work, THEN optimize.  Don't worry about performance until you're able to measure your code in action.

Comment: What is your intent with the database? Just logging purposes, to show users history, or even something else?

Comment: Bad advice.  I think you're right in planning your basic architecture with some sort of performance in mind.

Comment: @DanPichelman You can´t make it work on MySQL, just to decide to go with Redis or some IPC. That is - you can, but that high level of data abstraction might be to much to request by now.

Answer (score 9):

### MySQL is not ment for realtime

MySQL is clearly not the best solution for a chat: You have no reason to work on years of backlog to get the most current messages, nor do you want to fire a query per second for every active user. The overhead of a relational database is not to be ignored.

### Check out redis

I would go with [redis](http://try.redis.io/): It is an advanced key-value storage with capabilities of realtime interaction (PUB/SUB), automatic expire, and it is definitely faster than MySQL when it comes to loads of simple data.

**Edit:** Yes, it has all it´s data in ram. A Gb of ram would be enough for about every book in every libary of the world. That said, MySql also uses ram caching (query caching). And redis is ACID. (Oversimplified: You can enable saving to disk.)

### MySql hints, if you stick to it

If you yet decide to go with MySQL, you will have to write every single line into the DB for others to be visible. More explicit, you need a commit on every message. Make sure that you have some sort of cleanup mechanism, e.g. a cronjob moving all messages older than a day into some archive-tables.

### cache!

Imagine 100 users in your room, each checking every 3 seconds for new messages. 300 queries per second? (Ok, decent servers can handle this, but you asked for a good solution) Go another way: Have a memcached /redis-saved flag "Last message id". Change it every time someone writes something to the chat. Now make the client submit it´s last-known message id. If you´ve got a hit, exit immediately even without MySql starting up. If you are really good, you can make PHP even make to return the appropriate ETag.

### Long polls

As it comes to the frontend client: **Do not fire a reload or ajax request every n seconds!** Inform yourself about Websocket and **long polls**. That is a technique where the browser opens a site that will not immediately return a result, but will keep the connection open untill there is something to report (or timeout occurs)

### Edit: OP´s comment asking what programming language to use

That depends on your knowledge. I would go with PHP and redis, but that is because I know them well. If you prefer Java, use it. If you have no preference: Java is more versatile, php is easier to start learning. There is no objective one-size-fits-all-answer.

Comment: If it doesn't need to be a persistent store, maybe consider socket / streaming servers at that point.

Comment: I will take a look at redis. But I think that the middleware (maybe in dotnet or java) creates the objects that will be populated in order to send the requests to the db not everytime. Is it your solution without a middleware?

Comment: @MancoALeeCani I realise that I implicitly assumed you are using PHP. However, if you intend to make the realtime-part in JAVA and only need some backbone for long-term-archivation of the messages, Scribe might fit your needs. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribe_(log_server) Yet, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: In this case my question is... which is the best way? PHP or Scribe?

Comment: I need to implement something that looks like facebook buttttt not with that kind of complexity obviosly because I don't have a milions of account. I need a solution that can fit 100000 account (I hope :))

Comment: "I need something like facebook..." I hope you realise that thes spent propably about 1000 develper-years on the plattform? Something less complex would mean... well... 100 years of development? :-) But to comfort you: They use PHP, developed Scribe and love redis. Have fun :)

Comment: I'm reading that Redis is not good for persistend data cause it uses the RAM and if the Server goes down you lost information. I don't know if it could fit also for posts or whatever... I'm a new buy of redis so I'm sorry for this banal question :)

Comment: ahhahahahahha you're clearly right :) ... I need something that can be stable if the site grows up quickly. Assuming 100000 accounts I would like to be sure that the solution can fit this amount of users. Then I hope some company will take in consideration my idea...

Comment: I edited my answer. **That should be enough to get you going.** If you have further specific questions, please consider posting a **new question** to keep topics separated. And trust me: At the time you have so many users, you will have enough money to hire some performance-geeks.

Answer (score 0):

use NOSQL  as it store data as a file it is good for large database

Comment: So does mysql and just any persistent data storage - and that has no bearing on the suitability for large data or fast processing.

Answer (score 0):

Determine what features you want.  A few I can think of right off that might make a difference:

- Do you want to store the stream at all?  (If not, then your DB needs are minimal.)
- How much of the stream do you want accessible to users?  One day?  A week?  All of it?  (You can offload messages periodically to maintain history for yourself, but also keep the publicly-accessible DB small.)
- How many messages per minute / hour / day can a user post?  (Hint: not as many as they want)
- Do you want threading, or just one long stream that everyone can see?  (Increases complexity)
- Do you want users to be able to send private messages?  (Increases complexity)
- How often is the chat refreshed in the browser?  (The more it's refreshed, the larger the load on the server)

Comment: consider like the Facebook chat. Do you have an idea how FB chat works?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, sorry.